# QComboBox opens no matter where I tap (touchscreen)

Tags: c++, qt, touch, qcombobox

I have an otherwise working app that runs on a beaglebone black with a touch screen. I added a `QComboBox` to the app, and am experiencing some extremely strange behavior.

Prior to opening the `QComboBox`, all widgets work normally. Once the user touches the combo box, every subsequent touch anywhere in the window reopens the combo box. Tapping outside the combo box dropdown causes the dropdown to disappear, but causes the app to stop accepting touch inputs. Therefore the app is completely bricked at this point. I know the screen is responding correctly because the cursor still moves when I click and I can still close the app by clicking the X.

To ensure my existing code wasn't somehow causing this behavior, I replicated the situation in a new app consisting of just a `QComboBox`and a `QPushButton`.
The code for the test project is below, but I everything is autogenerated by qt except the slot for the button press, which just changes the background color of the button to red on click.

My question is

1) What the heck is going on?

2) Does this happen for other people or is my Qt broken?

3) How can I fix it?

Here's the code for the test app:

Test.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-03-28T15:03:35
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain 
version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs 
deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

unix {
    target.path = /home/debian
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: red; } ");
}
```

Here's how my test app looks:

[image: test app]

Comment: Why Qt4? Such old version has very poor support of touch input. And widgets originally has no support for touch input - touch input is simulating clicks. It is much better to use `QtQuick` for touch apps.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov my Qt version is actually 5.2, I must have tagged it incorrectly. When making the project, the widgets app was the only one that seemed to work with the beaglebone. The `QtQuick` apps all say my kit is not valid; I think they require Qt 5.7 or higher